# Dual citizen (Australia and UK) with different surname on each passport. Which passport do I use to book and to travel?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, dual-nationality, uk-citizens, australian-citizens

I have dual citizenship (Australia & UK).

Both passports have a different surname. The first and middle names are identical in both passports.

I’m planning a return trip from Australia to the UK. I’m really confused about which passport to use and the extra complexity of having a different surname on each passport.

Which passport do I use to book my flights?
Which passports do I use at each stage of my travel.

On the way there:

- check in when leaving Australia
- immigration when leaving Australia
- boarding the flight
- entering the UK

On the way back:

- check in when leaving the UK
- boarding the flight
- entering Australia

Comment: How long are you planning on staying in the UK?

Comment: I’ll be in the UK for 1 month.

Comment: Yes, MJeffryes, this totally helps!

Comment: You could just use your Australian passport the whole way. The UK doesn't have any requirement to use your UK passport when entering/leaving like Australia does. Australians can use the passport gates at LHR now, so there's really no advantage to using your UK passport at all.

Answer (score 4):

A very common reason for having different surnames in two passports is a dual citizen who changed their name when they got married. It is completely normal to have one passport updated with their new name and one with their old name. If this is your situation, then bringing a marriage certificate will help remove any confusion.

If you have changed your name for a different reason, then bringing whatever supporting documentation you have will be helpful.